# Can't start a server in BlackBox

Tags: server, pascal, oberon, component-pascal

I'm trying to start a server in BlackBox and so far I have just this

```
    MODULE server;
        IMPORT Dialog,Strings,Win:=WinApi, Server:=CommObxStreamsServer, Stream:=CommStreams;

    BEGIN
        Server.Start();
        Server.Stop();
    END server.
```

and when I run it I get the error
`server:error starting the server(2)`. I looked up that error 2 means invalid local address but start method doesn't require any arguments and I don't get where should I specify my local address:
[code from documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODdPT.png) (theories: do i need to start a new listener myself? are default ports busy? (upd:it's 900 and it's open))

SOLVED! In CommObxStreamsServer file:
`localAdr="900"` change to `localAdr="localhost:900"`

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  I suggest you add what you're said in your "SOLVED ..." as an answer as questions with answers tend to be of more help to future readers at SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CommObxStreamsServer file: `localAdr="900"` should be changed to `localAdr="localhost:900"`